# Java scheduled thread kills database

Tags: mysql, multithreading, spring, jakarta-ee, scheduledexecutorservice

Tools: Spring 3.0, Hibernate 2.0, Java 6

Most of the similar threads suggested  installing missing libs, correcting the configuration files etc but my project is working completely fine. One module is creating problems

**What I want to do:** Create a thread at applicaiton startup. Log the user requests in a web app., put them in a queue. Thread reads the queue after every 60 seconds and calls the transactional method to persist the queue.

**Data Structure:** ConcurrentLinkedQueue - which is initialized only once, when the bean is created

```
<bean id="userRequestLogger" class="com.emumba.sample.util.requestlog.UserRequestLogger"
init-method="init">
```

Definition of `init()`

```
public class UserRequestLogger {
    public void init() {        
        taskQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Task>();
    } 

    // Doing something here and then add the task to the queue
    // Tasks are added to the Queue from time to time. ( depends of user inputs) 
    taskQueue.add(task);

}
```

**The Thread:** In another class, a thread is scheduled to execute after a fixed time interval of 60 seconds

```
public void periodFunc() {

    private static final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors
        .newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

    final Runnable periodicTask = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            logger.info("Time's up!");

            userRequestLogManager.save();
        }           
    };

    final ScheduledFuture<?> taskHandler = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(
            periodicTask, 60, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

**Persistence:** Definition of `save()`

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class UserRequestLogManager extends

public void save() {

    ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Task> taskQueue = getTaskQueue();

    logger.info("Thread started - Name: "+ Thread.currentThread().getName());

    while( taskQueue != null && !taskQueue.isEmpty() ) {
        Task task = taskQueue.poll();

        if (task != null) {
            dao.persist(task);
        }
    }
...
}
```

**Applicaiton logs:**

```
2013-06-03 16:35:59,928 [pool-18-thread-1] INFO  com.emumba.sample.util.requestlog.UserRequestLogThreadLifeCycleHandler - Time's up!
2013-06-03 16:35:59,928 [pool-18-thread-1] INFO  com.emumba.sample.business.UserRequestLogManager - Thread started - Name: pool-18-thread-1
...
...
```

Application runs wihtout any issues on local machine, but on server (Amazon AWS bitnami tomcatstack), after a few hours the app. can't access database(MySQL). Apparentely, MySQL dies. It could be because of too many orphan connections or something, but I've yet to figure that out.

`mysql -u root -p` generates this error `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/opt/bitnami/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)`

**StackTrace:**

```
2013-06-03 16:35:59,928 [pool-18-thread-1] INFO  com.emumba.sample.util.requestlog.UserRequestLogThreadLifeCycleHandler - Time's up!
2013-06-03 16:35:59,928 [pool-18-thread-1] INFO  com.emumba.sample.business.UserRequestLogManager - Thread started - Name: pool-18-thread-1
2013-06-03 16:36:59,942 [pool-18-thread-1] INFO  com.emumba.sample.util.requestlog.UserRequestLogThreadLifeCycleHandler - Time's up!
2013-06-03 16:37:29,940 [pool-18-thread-1] ERROR org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction - JDBC begin failed
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 86,892 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 27,333 milliseconds ago.
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1116)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3090)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2979)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3520)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1990)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2151)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2619)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.setAutoCommit(ConnectionImpl.java:4997)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection.setAutoCommit(NewProxyConnection.java:881)
        at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:87)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1473)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:60)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.DefaultJpaDialect.beginTransaction(DefaultJpaDialect.java:70)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:332)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:371)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:335)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:105)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:621)
        at com.emumba.sample.business.UserRequestLogManager$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$306c3b43.save(<generated>)
        at com.emumba.sample.util.requestlog.UserRequestLogThreadLifeCycleHandler$1.run(UserRequestLogThreadLifeCycleHandler.java:54)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:317)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:150)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:204)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:2540)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2990)
        ... 28 more
2013-06-04 07:16:28,273 [http-bio-8181-exec-8] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
2013-06-04 07:16:41,631 [http-bio-8181-exec-8] ERROR com.emumba.sample.web.DefaultExceptionHandler - org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:382)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:371)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:335)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:105)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:621)
        at com.emumba.sample.business.ref.EntityRefManager$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$39d59864.findAll(<generated>)
        at com.emumba.sample.web.DefaultController.showHome(DefaultController.java:106)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:436)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:424)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:669)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:574)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:369)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:112)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:177)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:168)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:113)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1215)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1148)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1225)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:63)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.DefaultJpaDialect.beginTransaction(DefaultJpaDialect.java:70)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:332)
        ... 67 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
        at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:140)
        at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:128)
        at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
        at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:52)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:449)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:160)
        at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:81)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1473)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:60)
        ... 69 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
        at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:106)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:529)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:128)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:71)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
        ... 74 more
Caused by: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.CannotAcquireResourceException: A ResourcePool could not acquire a resource from its primary factory or source.
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1319)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:557)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:477)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:525)
        ... 77 more
2013-06-04 07:17:33,817 [http-bio-8181-exec-8] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
2013-06-04 07:17:33,830 [http-bio-8181-exec-8] ERROR org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - HandlerInterceptor.afterCompletion threw exception
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:382)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:371)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:335)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:105)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:621)
        at com.emumba.sample.business.UserSessionLogManager$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$34901c50.getActiveUserSessionLog(<generated>)
        at com.emumba.sample.util.requestlog.UserRequestLogger.log(UserRequestLogger.java:81)
        at com.emumba.sample.interceptor.UserRequestLogInterceptor.afterCompletion(UserRequestLogInterceptor.java:53)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.triggerAfterCompletion(DispatcherServlet.java:1108)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:830)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:669)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:574)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:684)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:593)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:530)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:954)
        at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.exception_jsp._jspService(exception_jsp.java:124)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:684)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:471)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:402)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:329)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1047)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:817)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:669)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:574)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:369)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:112)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:177)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:168)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:113)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
        at ....
```

I hope it makes sense.

Comment: You didn't post the code of your DAO.  Is it using a connection pool?  If not, is it using a new connection for every persistence task?  And if so is it closing those connections?

Comment: @Ireeder I can't add any more in text, so putting it here in comments. 
`DAO`
     `@PersistenceContext public EntityManager em;
        ...
     public Serializable persist(T entity) {
      if (entity == null) {
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot persist null entity.");
      }
      em.persist(entity);
      return entity.getId();
     }`
And here are some JPA Transacation manager configurations
`<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        ...
    </bean>`

Comment: I am using **C3P0** datasource `<bean id="dataSource" 
          class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" 
          destroy-method="close">`

Answer (score 1):

First, could it be that requests come in at such a high rate that the periodic run never gets out of polling the queue?

Second, are you sure you are not firing multiple background threads to process the queue?

Third, make sure the connection pool size is large enough.

Fourth, take a JVM thread dump when you get the DB exception to see how many threads are actually contending for JDBC connections, or use e.g. JVisualVM to profile.

Comment: You register the periodic task in the periodFunc method, where is that called? Also, you have made the save() method @Transactional and you are looping within it. That can create lengthy/large transactions. Add some logging to see how the background thread behaves. Also, did you think about the first point I made in my answer?

Comment: Method `periodFunc` is annotated with `@PostConstruct public void periodFunc()` so it will called only once on application load time.
Keep in mind that the thread will periodically run after 60 seconds, reads the queue (`.poll()`) and persists the data.

Comment: Sorry for being nieve, I'm new to threading. Let's say the task are added to the queue(`ConcurrentLinkedQueue`) constantly, will it be impossible for thread to read (`queue.remove()` or `queue.poll()`) the concurrent queue because it always busy storing taks? Or lets put it in another way, if the thread is busy removing or polling data from an infinite queue, will it be impossible to store any new data until it is empty?

Comment: So you appear to be running only a single thread for the scheduled task. That should be fine. The queue can be read from and written to concurrently by different threads. Now if the queue is constantly getting new items, it can happen that the thread emptying it will never be able to empty it fully and will stay in the loop (and transaction thereof) forever. Add logging to see if the background task ever exits the queue polling loop.

Answer (score 0):

OK here is how we solved the issue in a neat way. We did not launch any threads manually instead used Spring provided task execution and scheduling. Here is a good explanation http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/scheduling.html and a few example over here http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-and-java-thread-example/.

We also used @Async to run our methods asynchronously like

```
@Async
public void persistAsync(UserRequestLog userRequestLog) {
    this.persist(userRequestLog);
}
```

Hope it helps someone